# Why does a Boeing 747-8 take more runway length to take off, compared to an Airbus A380?

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff, boeing-747, airbus-a380

The Airbus A380 is the largest passenger airliner. That also includes the Boeing 747-8. Meaning, the Boeing 747-8 is smaller than the Airbus A380. As far as I know, smaller planes use less runway length to take off, compared to bigger planes. So, the Boeing 747-8 should consume less runway length than the Airbus A380 to take off, right?

I went to Google, and searched how much runway length is required for a Boeing 747 to take off. The top result showed 3040 m. I then searched how much runway length is required for an Airbus A380 to take off. The top result showed 2900 m.

How is this possible?

Comment: The Airbus A380 is the largest commercial airliner in the world, but is not the largest of "all the planes" ... for that see [Antonov A-255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya)

Comment: "smaller planes use less runway length to take off, compared to bigger planes" not absolutely true. The very small F104 (17m long, 6 m wide) needs 1.4 km of runway to take off. The avro RJ100 (30m long, 26m wide) needs1.2 km of runway.
And the RJ100 weights 4 times the F104, but it has only 3 times the thrust (ea. engine provides 30kN, while the single engine in the F104 provides 44kN, 65 kN with afterburner)

Comment: @CGCampbell that very much depends on which metric you use - the H-4 Hercules for example has a larger wingspan than the AN-225.

Answer (score 22):

This table compares some relevant numbers for the two aircraft:

| Aircraft | Airbus A380 | Boeing 747-8i |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MTOW | 575 000 kg | 447 700 kg |
| Wing Area | 845 m² | 554 m² |
| Wing Loading | 680 kg/m² | 808 kg/m² |
| Thrust | 4x 348 kN | 4x 296 kN |
| Thrust / Weight | 2.42 N/kg | 2.64 N/kg |

<sup>(All values from Wikipedia ([A380](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A380#Specifications_(A380-800,_Trent_engines)), [747-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747-8#Specifications)), all at MTOW, standard sea level conditions)</sup>

As you can see, the 747-8 has a slightly higher thrust to weight ratio (about 9% higher), which means it can accelerate a bit faster (at MTOW). However, the A380's wing is much larger resulting in a smaller wing loading (about 14% lower) at MTOW. This results in a lower takeoff speed and therefore reduces the required runway for takeoff.

If you want to compare the takeoff distances at different takeoff weights, I recommend to look at the Airport Planning Documents. These will contain graphs like these:

[image: A380 takeoff]
<sup>([Airbus Aircraft Characteristics](https://www.airbus.com/en/aircraft-characteristics) document for the A380, ISA conditions, Trent 900 engines)</sup>

[image: B747-8 takeoff]
<sup>([Boeing Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning](https://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/plan_manuals.page) document for the 747-8)</sup>

The second graph shows that at MTOW the 747-8 requires a little over 3000 m of runway for takeoff (at sea level). At the *same weight* (about 448 t), the A380 only requires about 1750 m according to the first chart. This is because it has a much lower wing loading of only 530 kg/m² now. With a 3000 m runway, the A380 can lift off at over 570 t, more than 100 t heavier than the 747-8.

Comment: This is key: lower wing loading means lower liftoff speed.

Comment: Since the existing version of the A380 is the one with the short fuselage, the "real" A380 would have a higher wing loading and, consequently, a higher takeoff distance. Pity it never went into production but hampered the version which did with a too large wing.

Comment: Then remove some wing surface area, preferably on the ends where it impedes access and flow at airports.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica then you have a plane that can access existing airports, but it needs a 7.5 km runway :)

Comment: And the two have similar displacement (?). When I start adding too much wing in KSP I can't get up to speed.

Comment: @Mazura I'm not sure what you mean by "displacement". Maybe you are referring to *coefficient of drag* $c_D$? According to [this Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient#Aircraft) the A380 has a lower $c_D$ than the 747. However, the value strongly depends on angle of attack, so I'm not sure how comparable these numbers are...

Comment: More wing and a lower coefficient? That's cheating.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Redesigning a wing is a ridiculously major undertaking, which is why they developed only the one wing with room for future 'stretch' variants built in from the beginning. There's absolutely no way that there would be enough of a market for an A380 with shorter wings to justify the development cost. They don't even have enough demand to justify the continued production of the existing one.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to add:

> [image]
> <sub>— Loftin Jr, Laurence K. "[Subsonic aircraft: Evolution and the matching of size to performance](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19800020744)." (1980).</sub>

Note how there are widebodies that need less runway than some narrowbodies.

If you play around with wing-loading, T/W ratio, and $C_L$, you can get the same or even better result. For instance, the A380 has [less wing sweep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Giant_planes_comparison.svg), which lowers the takeoff distance (increases the $C_L$ in the relation above). Case in point, the A380's indicative performance [V2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_speeds#Regulatory_V-speeds) speed is [150 kts](https://skybrary.aero/aircraft/a388), compared to [175 kts](https://skybrary.aero/aircraft/b748) for the 747-8.